# How to compare dates in Java using comparison operators?

Tags: java, date, comparison, boolean-expression, comparison-operators

How do I compare dates in Java using comparison operators?

Example:

date1 is `30-10-2017` 
 date2 is `31-10-2017` 
 date3 is `30-10-2018`

`date2` returns false when it should be true that it is less than `date3`. How can I return true if the date is less than another date and false otherwise?

This is my code: 
`return (day < theDate.day) || (month < theDate.month) || (year < theDate.year);`

Below is my current solution:

```
{
  boolean check = false;
  if(year < theDate.year)
  {
      return true;
  }
  if(year > theDate.year)
  {
      return false;
  }
  if(month < theDate.month)
  {
      check = true;
  }
  if(day < theDate.day)
  {
      check = true;
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }
  return check;
}
```

Comment: I don't think java accepts comparison operators on dates. but you can use  the `LocalDate` API along with the `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods.

Comment: What is the type of your date-class? (fully qualified) Is it `java.util.Date`, or is it `java.time.LocalDate` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2017, 10, 30); // Year, month, day.
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2017, 10, 31);
LocalDate date3 = LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 30);

System.out.printf("%s before %s? %s%n", date1, date2, date1.isBefore(date2));
System.out.printf("%s before %s? %s%n", date2, date3, date3.isBefore(date3));
System.out.printf("%s before %s? %s%n", date3, date1, date3.isBefore(date1));
```

If you want to know how to do a comparison yourself:

- Compare first year, then month, then day: from *most significant* to *least*
- For this reason the ISO standard of denoting dates (and times) is `2017-09-30T13:05:01,000` where a text comparison with a representation of the same length suffices.

And the pattern goes:

1. if years not equal then result found
2. if months not equal then result found
3. result is comparison of days

Answer (score 0):

You can't use relational operators directly, but date/time types typically implement `Comparable`.

So you should be able to do `date1.compareTo(date2) < 0` for logical `date1 < date2`.

Comment: I am comparing numeric values I set for the date objects. The fields I am using are integers for day, month, and year. So I am trying to check those values.

Comment: @julianrios I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: This is an assignment for my intro to java class. So I'm just a bit lost. I am coding in bluej and I don't believe I can access api for this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `boolean after(Date date)` or `boolean before(Date date)` for that. 
For example, `date2.before(date3)`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: @julianrios What class do you use for dates?

Comment: Is there a way to insert my all of my code? It may be easier to just look at what I have in my fields and methods.

Comment: @julianrios You can push "edit" under your question and add something